# Draggable elements sometimes jump back to their original position after appearing in the droppable element for a split second

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

So I don't want there to be a clone - I want to just drag the element without it still showing the element in the original position. I tried just hiding the original element when I'm dragging (the thing you're dragging with your mouse is the clone, not the original). So when I press the mouse down, I hide the original.

This worked well, except now when I drag multiple elements from the DROPPABLE element back to the original draggable place(which is also droppable), then SOMETIMES it doesn't let me do it - if I try to drag it back, it shows up for a split second in the original element, but then disappears and shows up in the droppable element.

Here is my .draggble code -

```
   $( "li", $gallery ).draggable({                             
       revert: "invalid", 
       containment: "document",
       helper: "clone",
       cursor: "pointer",

       start: function() {
         $(this).hide();
         },

       stop: function() {
         $(this).show();
         }

    });
```

This is inside an each function - the function goes through the elements of an array and makes draggable functions using the elements.

So again it works most of the time, but when I drag multiple elements into the second place, and then try  to drag them back, SOMETIMES it doesn't let me.

Here is the example code: http://jsfiddle.net/QzJb6/

Try dragging all 4 users into the "Nurses" subgroup, and then try to drag them all back to their original place. You'll see sometimes it jumps back.